# Bandpass filtering at low frequencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, signal-processing, bandpass-filter

I would like to know if there is any best practice to solve the following problem which I think may be of general interest.

I have a signal sampled with 40 kHz for about 60s. That signal contains frequencies up to 5kHz but I am only interested in its 40 Hz component.

How can I get a stable, narrow bandpass filtered (around 40 Hz) signal which also has the same time base as the original signal (zero lag). The filter should also have a linear phase.

Computational efforts are not an issue.

Comment: In Matlab, I would try `butter` to design the filter. Use zero-pole-gain output (rather than numerator and denominator of transfer function, which cause numerical instability even for low filter orders). Then convert to SOS format. Then you can use `filtfilt`, which applies the filter twice: normally and time-reversed. That ensures linear phase; it also effectively doubles the filter order and squares the absolute value of the transfer function. See the examples [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html)

Comment: Designing and applying a filter is a good approach when you want to filter some signal in real-time. If you are just interested in manipulating a certain chunk of a signal, it might be worthwhile to apply a window before doing a FFT and then simply set the undesired frequency bins to zero and transform the manipulated spectrum back to the time domain via the IFFT. In a sense, this approach is like applying a perfect low-pass filter to your signal.

Comment: These are very interesting approaches. However, I do need to filter in real-time since I need to have a new signal which only consists of the 40 Hz component of the original signal for further processing. Not only a chunk of the original signal. I will try to implement it as suggested by @LuisMendo for further discussion.

Comment: The real-time requirement changes everything. It wasn’t clear in the question that you needed real time. In that case I can’t offer any help

Comment: Sorry, I think I got this wrong. What I mean is I have captured the signal and then want to post-process it such that the new signal will only have the 40 Hz component of the original signal but the same time base and linear phase. However, I need to process the whole signal and not only a chunk of it.

Comment: I think my comment mentioning a "chunk" was misleading. What I meant was that you can simply use a FFT/IFFT to postprocess the whole signal you recorded. In contrast if you want to build a system which continuously filters a signal that is sampled in real-time (like from a microphone or any data source/sensor) that you might want to design a filter and do your best to suppress the undesired frequencies in your signal.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. In that case I will try out both recommend approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Design a narrow band pass filter using: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iirpeak.html
and then implement it on the signal using the a forward-backward filter, filtfilt:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html.

The forward-backward filtering requires sectioning of the signal but you can always produce sections with a large overlap.